# How to set a different max_file_size other than that of the .ini for a single file uploader script

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

Let's say I have `max_file_size` set to 20mb but I want to limit it to 4mb on a particular file only, how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$default_max_file_size = ini_get('upload_max_filesize');

if ($is_special_file) {
   ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '4M');

   // process your file

   // set it back to original value
   ini_set('upload_max_filesize', $default_max_file_size);
}
```

Comment: If it works, it's really good, but what if an error happens before resetting the max_filesize on ini, there seems not to be any other way?